# Does this planar graph property have a name, and what does it imply?

Tags: co.combinatorics

I'm working on [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/28909) problem (rather out-of-date post, sorry) from two directions simultaneously. You can read a bit about my geometric approach [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/68721), and this question is about the combinatorial approach.

It's pretty intuitive that the graph of any half-decent polyhedron in the sense of my problem will have the following property: if a circuit of length L encloses A or V-A vertices, where 2A ≤ V the total number of vertices, then L<sup>2</sup>/A ≥ some value on the order of 2π. In other words, there are no short loops enclosing large numbers of vertices. This feels like quite a strong property, but I'm not completely sure. Anyway, as the question says: does this have a name, and are there any nice properties that it implies so I can narrow my combinatorial search a bit?

Incidentally, I think some sort of converse of this property is also likely to hold: namely, a large enough "convex" loop (one that can't be shortened by enlarging its interior) should contain lots of vertices, i.e. L<sup>2</sup>/A ≤ some value on the order of 4π.

Comment: Can you summarize what is "any half-decent polyhedron in the sense of my problem"?  The reason I ask is that a convex curve can enclose an arbitrarily large number of vertices of low curvature.  But perhaps such polyhedra are excluded from your problem?

Comment: They're not automatically excluded, but recall that the number of faces (and hence vertices) is bounded. If you took most of those vertices and moved them outside the curve, you'd end up with a much more spherical polyhedron.

Here's a concrete example, which in fact motivated my definition: http://math.ca/cjm/v15/cjm1963v15.0744-0751.pdf defines a family of cylinder-like fullerenes, with a circumference formed by six hexagonal faces. It's possible to make such a polyhedron roughly spherical, but this "narrow waist" forces it to stick out in an angular fashion. Does that answer your question?

Comment: @Robin: Actually, I still don't understand the class of polyhedra under consideration :-).  But that's OK.  I would have to penetrate the earlier MO postings and the cited papers to fully understand. In any case, I am grateful for the interesting references.

Comment: I'll try to put it in more intuitive terms anyway - if my wording was awkward for you, I'm sure there are other readers who haven't spoken up.

Essentially, you'd expect a "round" polyhedron to have faces (or vertices) distributed roughly evenly across the surface of the sphere they were approximating - so a short loop of edges would be physically small. All this property says, then, is that there aren't too many vertices concentrated in one place. But it phrases it in purely combinatorial terms.

Comment: @Robin: It's not that your wording is unclear; rather it is that one must absorb two other longish MO posts, and some of the cited literature, to understand your current question.

Comment: @"rather out-of-date post, sorry": we welcome comments/answers/etc to these - there is no "old" on the web - so no apology necessary!

Answer (score 1):

This seems to have a lot to do with "toughness", and its various variants. Googling "planar graph toughness" gives a bunch of references, some of which might be relevant. Look also at the papers of Mike Dillencourt, who has connected toughness with a number of other graph properties.